# ipad - sort data in UITableView (DESC)

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting

I have NSArray, where I have numbers and I need to sort data in tableView by those numbers in DESC. I've found `NSSortDescriptor`, but I don't know, how to use it... Can you help me?

Comment: Have you read some tutorial or tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simple sort arrays using the block methods:

```
NSArray *orderedObjects = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
   return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}];
```

to invert the order just switch the objects in compare:

```
NSArray *orderedObjects = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
   return [obj2 compare:obj1];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use NSArray's sortUsingComparator:  Below, you can find an example snippet that would sort an NSArray named array in descending order.

```
[array sortUsingComparator: ^(id id1, id id2) {
    NSNumber* num1 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)id1];
    NSNumber* num2 = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)id2];
    return [num1 compare:num2];
}];
```

The block uses an array of ints, and calls sortUsingComparator.  The block header will always be the same, the contents are what will change based on how you want to sort (and what you want to sort).